# How to exclude certain data from Firestore query

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to populate my FirestoreUI recyclerview with the 5 most popular users in that database (By sorting "subscribers"), but at the same time check if the user has already added them as a friend by checking if the user-id of the famous person is already under the "friends" collection under their own user-id document.

Is there a way of excluding a user which has already been added? Is this also possible while having 5 entries?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to check against data that's in multiple collections, you won't be able to do that with a single Firestore query.  (There are no "join" queries in Firestore.)  You also can't write queries to selectively exclude certain values from fields.

With your current structure, you will have to first load up all the relevant friends in memory.  Then you could set up a paged query for users, and page through it until you find enough documents that match your criteria that you check individually in client code.